# The onClick on the unodered list is not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, jsx, bind

The on onclick function which should call the function which is HTML inside Java-script (JSX). Does not seems to work??

Does onClick only works on a button or does it also work on the lists too?

```
class Top extends React.Component{
constructor(){
    super();
    this.searchjsx = this.searchjsx.bind(this);
}

searchjsx = () =>{
    return(
        <div id='searchdiv'>
            <form id='searchform'>
                <input type="text" id="input" name="search"></input>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
render(){
    return(
        <div>
        <div id="navbar">
            <ul id="nav">
                <li><a className="a" href='https://www.google.com/'>Home</a></li>
                <li><a  className="b" href='https://www.google.com/'>Profile</a></li>
                <li><a className="c" href='https://www.google.com/'>Pricing</a></li>
                <li onClick={this.searchjsx} id='sch'>Search..</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div>

        </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried putting `alert` or `console.log` inside `searchjsx()` to test if click is working or not?

Comment: Your handler works, it's just that returning JSX from a normal event handler doesn't do anything

Comment: Yes,  i  tried console logging it worked. but the jsx part is not working

Comment: @CertainPerformance , what do i do.

Comment: This onClick function doesn't work on any element; try to use on other elements. Won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below worked for me:

```
import React from "react";

export default class Top extends React.Component {
  state = {
    showForm: false
  };

  searchjsx = () => {
    console.log("Toggled showForm");
    this.setState({ showForm: !this.state.showForm });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="navbar">
          <ul id="nav">
            <li>
              <a className="a" href="https://www.google.com/">
                Home
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a className="b" href="https://www.google.com/">
                Profile
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a className="c" href="https://www.google.com/">
                Pricing
              </a>
            </li>
            <li onClick={this.searchjsx} id="sch">
              Search..
            </li>
            {this.state.showForm ? (
              <div id="searchdiv">
                <form id="searchform">
                  <input type="text" id="input" name="search"></input>
                </form>
              </div>
            ) : (
              ""
            )}
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Notes:

1. onclick should work on any element
2. You were trying to insert the form inside the onClick attribute. Instead, you should change the state of the component when li is clicked and based on the state show or hide the form
3. You don't seem to need a constructor in this example

Comment: showForm is initially false because we want the form displayed only when the "Search.." li is clicked.

 **state = { showForm: false};**

When the user clicks the li, you must toggle the value of showForm with the ! operator.

 **this.setState({ showForm: !this.state.showForm });**

Lastly, you have to display the form below the li only if showForm is true using the ternary operator **?:**

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";

export default class Top extends React.Component{
state = {
  show:false
}

showInput() {
  return(
    <div id='searchdiv'>
      <form id='searchform'>
        <input type="text" id="input" name="search"></input>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
handleShow() {
  this.setState({
    show: !this.state.show
  })
}
render(){
  return(
      <div>
      <div id="navbar">
          <ul id="nav">
              <li><a className="a" href='https://www.google.com/'>Home</a></li>
              <li><a  className="b" href='https://www.google.com/'>Profile</a></li>
              <li><a className="c" href='https://www.google.com/'>Pricing</a></li>
              <li onClick={e => this.handleShow(e)} id='sch'>Search..</li>
             {
               this.state.show ? this.showInput() : null
             } 
          </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

- You have to maintain a state variable that can control when to display a component. In this case, **show**.